# Equality of two anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, reference-type

I have the following code

```
var arr = [];
$("#Target").click(function () {
    function Stuff() {
        console.log("Dummy");
    }
    var found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        found = found || arr[i] == Stuff;
    }
    if (!found)
        arr.push(Stuff);
    alert(arr.length);
});
```

Each time I click the button it increases the count of the array. However, if I modify the code like this

```
function Stuff() {
    console.log("Dummy");
}
var arr = [];
$("#Target").click(function () {
    var found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        found = found || arr[i] == Stuff;
    }
    if (!found)
        arr.push(Stuff);
    alert(arr.length);
});
```

It detects the equality and array contains 1 element at max. <del>What is happening here is that each time `click` event is fired, anonymous handler is instantiated again, so is `Stuff` function.</del>
In the first code block anonymous function is instantiated each time the event fired. In the second code block, as the `Stuff` function is a global function (read "property of a `window` object") it is not instantiated.

My question is, is there an established way of testing equality of this kind of functions?

**PS:** I know that there is a workaround like

```
arr[i].toString() == Stuff.toString();
```

But I want to restrain this kind of "wizardry"

**Edit**

A bit more details: I want to create a function

```
$.throttle = function(func, delay){
    // Here I need to check whether this function was already passed,
    // and if yes, I need to clear previous timeout and create new
}
```

and it may be called like this

```
$.throttle(function () { console.log("Foo"); }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 4):

> What is happening here is that each time `click` event is fired anonymous handler is instantiated again, so is `Stuff` function.

No, that's not what's happening in your second code block. Each time `click` fires, the **same** `Stuff` function is pushed onto the array; the anonymous function is just run by the `click` handler, not *instantiated* by it. (It's instantiated by the code hooking up the `click` handler.)

If you have two references to a function and want to know if they refer to the same function, you can compare them with `===` or `==`:

```
var ref1 = Stuff;
var ref2 = Stuff;
console.log(ref1 === ref2);  // true
console.log(ref1 === Stuff); // true
console.log(ref2 === Stuff); // true
```

If you want to create two different copies of a function (as in your first code block) and see if they have the same code, there's no official way to do that. You can compare the result of `toString` as you've pointed out (although the spec doesn't actually require `toString` to return code), but while that will compare their code content (if it works), it won't compare their *context*. Consider:

```
function foo(bar) {
    return function() {
        alert(bar);
    };
}
var f1 = foo("one");
var f2 = foo("two");
f1();                                         // alerts "one"
f2();                                         // alerts "two"
console.log(f1.toString() === f2.toString()); // true
```

The functions we got back from calling `foo` have the same code in them, but they are not equivalent functions. As far as I'm aware, there is no standard way of comparing functions for *equivalence*, only for identity.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I noticed some of my statements were vague. I edited my question correspondingly.

Comment: And yes, I do know that two functions with the same body may give totally different results. That is why, I want to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

*Functions* (in *JavaScript*) are *Objects* `(function () {}) instanceof Object`, and equality of *Objects* is done *ByRef*, i.e. identical is not equal

If you want to do something like you describe, you need to have a closure over the reference so you can access it, perhaps you want something like this

```
var arr = [];
$("#Target").click((function () {
    function Stuff() {
        console.log("Dummy");
    }
    return function () {
        var found = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            found = found || arr[i] == Stuff;
        }
        if (!found)
            arr.push(Stuff);
        alert(arr.length);
    };
}()); // note IIFE execution
```

What's different here? `Stuff` is only created once, but it is used by the `return`ed function which becomes the click handler

If you want to pass in abstract functions which may have been defined elsewhere, you can do it as parameters/args to the *IIFE*

```
function foo() {
    // ...
}

$("#Target").click((function (Stuff) {
    return function () {
        // `foo` is called `Stuff` here
    };
}(foo));
```

Comment: But why make it so obscure? Just put `function Stuff` outside the click handler hookup. Simple, easy to understand...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OP already knows moving `Stuff` outside the _click_ makes it work, so I think they were asking how to take it into the abstract? I'm not sure